# 2 Different F1-Measure to calculate clustering performance - which one is correct and why?

Tags: clustering, precision-recall, hierarchical-clustering, measurement

I know it sounds incorrect but that is the truth

Here let me show you

This below one is the first one and very widely used in the literature

[image]

First one reference : Steinbach, Michael, George Karypis, and Vipin Kumar. "A comparison of document clustering techniques." KDD workshop on text mining. Vol. 400. No. 1. 2000.

And the second one is this one : http://nlp.stanford.edu/IR-book/html/htmledition/evaluation-of-clustering-1.html

Here an answer about second one : https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/80194/5263

The second one is pretty complex and hard to understand

I coded both and they produce different results

I believe second one is better evaluation but the question is

Why there are 2 different F1-Measure?
Which one is better and why?

Comment: At the end of [your first page](http://nlp.stanford.edu/IR-book/html/htmledition/evaluation-of-clustering-1.html), it says $F_\beta = \frac{(1+\beta^2)PR}{\beta^2P + R}$, which, for $\beta = 1$, is the $F_1$ score. This is the $F_\beta$ score, a generalization (see [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/F1_score)). What did you mistake for the $F_1$ score in [your link](http://nlp.stanford.edu/IR-book/html/htmledition/evaluation-of-clustering-1.html)?

Comment: @Winks so you say F1-Score and F-Measure are different things?

Comment: @Winks because wikipedia tells F-Measure and F1-Score are same things

Comment: @Winks 1 more thing. How do you format your answer that way in comment section :D

Comment: You should give an example, your computations for the two methods, and the results obtained. For everyone to see how they differ. Don't be lazy, please.